# Getting the output shape of deconvolution layer using tf.nn.conv2d_transpose in tensorflow

Tags: neural-network, tensorflow, deep-learning, conv-neural-network

According to this [paper](http://www.matthewzeiler.com/pubs/cvpr2010/cvpr2010.pdf), the output shape is `N + H - 1`, `N` is input height or width, `H` is kernel height or width. This is obvious inverse process of convolution. This [tutorial](http://cs231n.github.io/convolutional-networks/) gives a formula to calculate the output shape of convolution which is `(W−F+2P)/S+1`, `W` - input size, `F` - filter size, `P` - padding size, `S` - stride. But in [Tensorflow](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/python/ops/nn_test.py), there are test cases like:

```
  strides = [1, 2, 2, 1]

  # Input, output: [batch, height, width, depth]
  x_shape = [2, 6, 4, 3]
  y_shape = [2, 12, 8, 2]

  # Filter: [kernel_height, kernel_width, output_depth, input_depth]
  f_shape = [3, 3, 2, 3]
```

So we use `y_shape`, `f_shape` and `x_shape`, according to formula `(W−F+2P)/S+1` to calculate padding size `P`. From `(12 - 3 + 2P) / 2 + 1 = 6`, we get `P = 0.5`, which is not an integer. How does deconvolution works in Tensorflow?

Answer (score 10):

for deconvolution,

```
output_size = strides * (input_size-1) + kernel_size - 2*padding
```

strides, input_size, kernel_size, padding are integer
padding is zero for 'valid'

Comment: I think padding is zero for "SAME" but for "VALID" it is some value.

Comment: @VatsalAggarwal please verify your comment. Size is the same for 'SAME'. So padding is added to maintain it

Answer (score 3):

The formula for the output size from the tutorial assumes that the padding `P` is the same before and after the image (left & right or top & bottom).
Then, the number of places in which you put the kernel is:
`W (size of the image) - F (size of the kernel) + P (additional padding before) + P (additional padding after)`.

But tensorflow also handles the situation where you need to pad more pixels to one of the sides than to the other, so that the kernels would fit correctly. You can read more about the strategies to choose the padding (`"SAME"` and `"VALID"`) in the [docs](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r0.7/api_docs/python/nn.html#convolution). The test you're talking about uses method `"VALID"`.

Answer (score 1):

This discussion is really helpful. Just add some additional information.
`padding='SAME'` can also let the bottom and right side get the one additional padded pixel. According to [TensorFlow document](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/nn/convolution), and the test case below

```
strides = [1, 2, 2, 1]
# Input, output: [batch, height, width, depth]
x_shape = [2, 6, 4, 3]
y_shape = [2, 12, 8, 2]

# Filter: [kernel_height, kernel_width, output_depth, input_depth]
f_shape = [3, 3, 2, 3]
```

is using padding='SAME'. We can interpret padding='SAME' as:

```
(W−F+pad_along_height)/S+1 = out_height,
(W−F+pad_along_width)/S+1 = out_width.
```

So `(12 - 3 + pad_along_height) / 2 + 1 = 6`, and we get `pad_along_height=1`. And `pad_top=pad_along_height/2 = 1/2 = 0`(integer division), `pad_bottom=pad_along_height-pad_top=1`.

As for padding='VALID', as the name suggested, we use padding when it is proper time to use it. At first, we assume that the padded pixel = 0, if this doesn't work well, then we add 0 padding where any value outside the original input image region. For example, the test case below,

```
strides = [1, 2, 2, 1]

# Input, output: [batch, height, width, depth]
x_shape = [2, 6, 4, 3]
y_shape = [2, 13, 9, 2]

# Filter: [kernel_height, kernel_width, output_depth, input_depth]
f_shape = [3, 3, 2, 3]
```

The output shape of `conv2d` is

```
out_height = ceil(float(in_height - filter_height + 1) / float(strides[1]))
           = ceil(float(13 - 3 + 1) / float(3)) = ceil(11/3) = 6
           = (W−F)/S + 1.
```

Cause `(W−F)/S+1 = (13-3)/2+1 = 6`, the result is an integer, we don't need to add 0 pixels around the border of the image, and `pad_top=1/2`, `pad_left=1/2` in the [TensorFlow document](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/nn/convolution) padding='VALID' section are all 0.

Comment: The answer is about `tf.nn.conv2d`, how does padding mode work for `tf.nn.conv2d_transpose`? `tf.nn.conv2d_transpose` will make the output tensor larger than input.