# Matching shapes when using tensorflow conv2d_transpose

Tags: tensorflow, convolution

I am trying to create a convolutional variational autoencoder using tensorflow. In the decoder, I am trying to use the `tf.layers.conv2d_transpose` to perform the upsampling. However, I cannot understand how to match the dimensions. For example, this is my code:

```
# shape: (-1, 26, 26, 32)
conv1 = tf.layers.conv2d(
     image_batch,
     filters=32,
     kernel_size=3,
     strides=1,
     activation=tf.nn.relu)

# shape: (-1, 24, 24, 16)
conv2 = tf.layers.conv2d(
    conv1,
    filters=16,
    kernel_size=3,
    strides=1,
    activation=tf.nn.relu)

#shape: (-1, 11, 11, 8)
conv3 = tf.layers.conv2d(
    conv2,
    filters=8,
    kernel_size=3,
    strides=2,
    activation=tf.nn.relu) 

#shape: (-1, 23, 23, 16)
deconv1 = tf.layers.conv2d_transpose(
    conv3,
    filters=16,
    kernel_size=3,
    strides=2)

#shape: (-1, 25, 25, 32)
deconv2 = tf.layers.conv2d_transpose(
    deconv1,
    filters=32,
    kernel_size=3,
    strides=1)

#shape: (-1, 27, 27, 1)
deconv3 = tf.layers.conv2d_transpose(
    deconv2,
    filters=1,
    kernel_size=3,
    strides=1)
```

```

We can see that the dimensions are not matching. Is there any mathematical formula that I should use to get back the correct dimensions or is there something wrong with my code ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Getting the output shape of deconvolution layer using tf.nn.conv2d\_transpose in tensorflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35980044/getting-the-output-shape-of-deconvolution-layer-using-tf-nn-conv2d-transpose-in)

Comment: Check this to get correct dimensions: http://cs231n.github.io/convolutional-networks/. Go to the summary section directly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem here is because of `conv3`. In `conv3`, you are using convolution with a stride of 2 and kernel size of 3. This constraints your input to be of odd shape, but, your input shape is `(24, 24, 16)`. Hence, the convolution is performed only on `(23, 23, 16)`, and the boundary pixels are ignored. You can refer to this [CS231N tutorial](http://cs231n.github.io/convolutional-networks/#conv) for more information on how to calculate the output shape.

Now, when you try to upsample from `(11, 11, 8)`, it will upsample to the shape from which it was obtained, i.e., `(23, 23, 16). So, this creates an error between your input shape and the upsampled shape.

There are multiple options that you can employ to get rid of this problem -

- Find the right combination of stride and kernel size, so that no values are ignored. This will keep your input shape and upsampled shape in coherence to each other.
- When you are upsampling, pad the output (on one side only) manually to create the shape of `(24, 24, 16)` from the shape `(23, 23, 16)`.
- Or, you can pad the final output after all the upsampling layers.